# Find the area of the region $y=2x$, the $x$-axis, lines $x=1$ and $x=4$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, summation, area

> Find the area of the region $y=2x$, the $x$-axis, lines $x=1$ and $x=4$

Here's what I did:

$$A = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1}f(x_{i-1})\Delta x
\\ = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1} 2(i-1)\Delta x^2 
\\ = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1} 2(i-1){ 9\over n^2}$$
Because$\Delta x = {b-a \over n} = {4-1 \over n} = {3\over n}$

$$= \lim_{n \to +\infty} {18 \over n^2}\sum^{n-1}_{i=1} i
\\ = \lim_{n \to +\infty}{18 \over n^2} \cdot{n(n+1)\over 2} 
\\ = \lim_{n \to +\infty}{18 \over n^2} \cdot{n(n-1)\over 2}
\\ = \lim_{n \to +\infty} {9(n-1)\over n}
\\ = \lim_{n \to +\infty} {9n \over n}-{1 \over n}
\\ = 9$$

I know this is wrong, because if I graph,

[image]

This is what I would get, 15.

What did I do wrong here?

I have to find the answer by using Riemann Sum

Thanks

Comment: why you didn't use integral method?

Comment: I haven't learned it  @Battani

Comment: At $i=1$ $f(x)$ must be $2$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that @Qwerty

Comment: @didgocks Leave that. Do you know how to calculate the area of the triangle?

Comment: Yes, the area is half of a square @Qwerty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One the second and third line giving $A$, you have made a mistake.

You rather have
$$
A=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum^{n}_{i=1}f(x_{i})\Delta x=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac3{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}2\left(1+\frac{3i}{n}\right)=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{15(n+1)}n=15.
$$

Comment: How do I know what $(x_i)$ equals?

Comment: Usually $x_i=a+\frac{(b-a)i}{n}$ is a nice choice.

Comment: Would still $\Delta x = {b -a \over n}$ sperately? or is your $x_i$ include the $\Delta x$?

Comment: One has $\Delta x_i =x_i-x_{i-1}= {b -a \over n}=\Delta x$

Comment: I just realized you used $(x_i)$ instead of $(x_{i-1})$ Is there a difference? And I heard that one is circumscribed rectangles and the other is inscribed rectangle

Comment: By definition of a Riemann sum, taking $x_i$ or $x_{i-1}$, the limits  are just the same: $\int_a^bf$.

Answer (score 1):

Required area=Area of triangle $(0,0)(4,0)(4,8)$-Area of triangle $(0,0)(1,0)(1,2)$ Why do you intend to do such complicacies?

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that I have to do it using Riemann sum.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you didn't mentiond to find are  by Riemann sum, so I suggest second method find it as follows :
$$S= S_\text{big}- S_\text{small}=\frac { 4\cdot 8 }{ 2 } -\frac {1\cdot 2} 2 =15$$